Finding the type of functions
I have a problem regarding finding the type in Haskell.
The question is as follows:

Find the type of uncurry curry

Does anyone know a way to find the type?
The answer should be ((b1, b2) -> c, b1) -> b2 -> c.
I know I can use :t to find the answer, but I want to do it by hand.

curry uncurry doesn't type-check at all. The given answer is the type of uncurry curry.

Yes, I was meant to write uncurry curry

Hint: consider the type presentations uncurry :: (d -> e -> f) -> (d, e) -> f and curry :: ((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c, then think of curry as a function that takes two arguments and returns a function of type b -> c. Now associate those types with d, e, and f as appropriate.

When i try to solve the question i get the answer: ((a,b) -> c, a) -> (a,b) -> c

Hint2: line up the signature of curry (((a, b) -> c) -> a -> (b -> c)) with the signature of the first parameter of uncurry (d -> e -> f) and then replace each occurrence of d, e, and f in the rest ((d, e) -> f) with what it lines up with.

Hint 0: learn the basics of Hindley-Milner type inference.

Here is a general template you can use for this kind of problem. First we'll write down the facts we know with no special thought put in.
uncurry       :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c
        curry :: ((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c

It happens that both types use the type variables a, b, and c, which is going to get confusing, since we don't (yet) know that they should be equal between the two signatures. So let's just rename one or the other signature.
uncurry       :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c
        curry :: ((d, e) -> f) -> d -> e -> f

Now, the typing rule for function application looks like this, roughly:
f   :: X -> Y
  x :: X
-------------
f x ::      Y

Things above the line are "inputs" to the typing rule, assumed to all be true, and things below the line are "outputs" of the typing rule, telling us new facts. The capital letters X and Y are metavariables -- this is actually an infinite collection of typing rules, with one rule for each pair of types you might choose to substitute in for X and Y. (The f and x are similarly metavariables standing in for any pair of expressions you like.) Let's fill in this template for uncurry curry, using a similarly suggestive whitespace regime for lining up things that ought to be equal.
uncurry       :: (a -> b -> c)                -> (a, b) -> c
        curry :: ((d, e) -> f) -> d -> e -> f
------------------------------------------------------------
uncurry curry ::                                 (a, b) -> c

There's one more rule we need to know before we can say we have fully stated the puzzle we're going to try to solve, which is that -> is injective. Using ~ for equality rather than = (for uninteresting social reasons), this means that (W -> X) ~ (Y -> Z) if and only if W ~ Y and X ~ Z. (There is a similar rule for type constructors like Maybe and Either.) We can reflect this fact into our suggestive whitespace by lining up arguments to ->. Remember that (->) is right-associative, that is, a -> b -> c means the same thing as a -> (b -> c).
uncurry       :: (a            -> b -> c     ) -> (a, b) -> c
        curry :: ((d, e) -> f) -> d -> e -> f
-------------------------------------------------------------
uncurry curry ::                                  (a, b) -> c

Can you see now how to choose instantiations of a, b, and c (in terms of d, e, and f) that will make these match up? Once you do, what is the instantiation of the type under the line?
To review, here's the process we used:

Write down any facts we know.
Rename variables to make sure they don't collide.
Use the typing rules for function application (and, in the more general case, other syntactic constructs like lambda, let, and case) to collect constraints about type variables and compute the final type in terms of those variables.
Use injectivity to break complicated constraints into simple constraints.
Solve all the simple constraints.
Use the solution to make the final type explicit.

This process should work for inferring the type of just about any expression; indeed, with a bit of work on making each of these steps more precise, this mimics quite closely what the compiler itself does.
